# How to check if drive in the raid array fails using ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to write an Ansible playbook to find out if the drive in the raid array `md0`, `md1` or `md2` is failed. And if it is failed then remove and re-add the drive. How can I do this check using Ansible.

Drive on the server is `/dev/nvme0n1` and `/dev/nvme1n1`.

Comment: Please help me on this

Comment: Where do you have difficulties to achieve this? Are you facing any error? Except writing the playbook for you, I don't really see how I can help you…

Answer (score 1):

There is no `mdadm` module ([yet…](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/40205)). So you will have to do it with `shell`/`command` module.

This is possible to be done in 2 tasks.

The first one, you gather the status (You can find a Answer on how to grep it [here on StackExchange](https://superuser.com/a/1368863))

```
- name: Get mdadm status
  command: >
    mdadm -D {{ md_device }} …
```

You have to register the output to check if any disk is failing:

```
  register: md_status
```

From there you can remove/add the disks:

```
- name: Attach/detach disk from RAID
  shell: |
     mdadm --manage {{ md_device }} --remove /dev/{{ drive }}
     mdadm --manage {{ md_device }} --add    /dev/{{ drive }}
```

With a `when` clause. (Sorry, I don't know by heart the output for failing disk).

```
  when: "FAILURE" in md_status
```

Of course you also have to deal with the loop on the `md_device` and the disk device, too. The logic there will depend of the output of `mdadm`…

Sorry if the answer is not really accurate. But your question is too vague on the problems you are facing.